# tabu list using Dictionary element

Tags: c#, dictionary, indexing, tabu-search

I am trying to implement a tabu list for a metaheuristic I am developing that will ban the movment of Patient objects to Room objects. I though the easiest way to do this would be to implement a    Dictionary where I would add Patient Room pairs to be tabued. The problem I countered with this is that, if I want the tabu list to be say 30 keys long and I want to be able to remove the last key-value pair every time a new one needs to be added I have to way of indexing the "oldest" entry in a Dictionary.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could do this in a smarter way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this on my own by implementing a

```
List<Dictionary<Patient,Room>>
```

and creating a new dictionary element for each element that needed to go in the tabu list. I used the `list.Add()` method and then checked the size of the list. If it exceeded a predefined maxsize I simply called `list.RemoveAt(0)`.